# 2009 Ford Focus...Will these 15" rims fit?

Tags: ford, volvo, wheels

I have a set of 15" Volvo rims: Rim: 6x15 ET43, Bolt pattern: 5x108, Thread Size: M12 x 1.75, Center Bore: 65.1 The 2009 Ford Focus Rim Specs: Rim: 6x15 ET52.5, Bolt pattern: 5x108, Thread Size: M12 x 1.5, Center Bore: 63.3 Will the Volvo Rims fit and what other vehicles, Ford, etc. will they fit?

Answer (score 2):

You have a 9.5mm difference in offset between the two, and a 1.8mm difference in centre bore - so they will physically fit, but it is not recommended.

The difference in offset means that the wheels will sit further in towards the centre of the car. This could lead to rubbing against the suspension or arches, although you should be able to check this to find out whether or not it will be a problem

The difference in centre bore means that the wheel will be less positively located on the hub - the bolts will hold it properly*, but this can increase the stress on the bolts.

*providing you have the right shape bolts, bearing in mind that you can't use the Volvo bolts on the Ford as they have different thread patterns. Bolts can have different tapers, different diameter shoulders and may or may not include a captive washer, which itself can be different sizes... Using the wrong bolts will mean you can't tighten them properly, with the risk of them working loose and the wheels falling off...

Answer (score 2):

They will absolutely fit, there are a few things you will need to do before running them, one is you are going to need or should use hub-centric rings to make that center bore the same size, otherwise expect vibrations at high speeds.

Also you may want to run a spacer, because of the difference in offset with the volvo wheels.  You should be able to source a 10mm spacer for pretty cheap and you may even be able to find a custom fabrication shop specializing in spacers make a hub centric spacer that will adapt the center bore for you as well.

Make sure you lug nuts are the correct tapper, it will either be conical or spherical, and then use the bolts that are the same thread as your car and meet the correct tapper.

Thats it, many guys run wheels this way, I have been with many different wheels on many different cars at high-speeds on a track environment with no issues.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know would be to fit one of the Volvo wheels to the Ford at the front **and** to the rear to check for any obstructions or fouling through the wheels full travel. This will cover the physical fitment of the Volvo wheels. Another important consideration is that the wheel from the Ford would have been selected as part of the specification for the Ford suspension set up. If wheel rim off-set of the Volvo differs from the Ford then this may produce undesirable effects such as increased tyre wear, tyre noise, or over or under steer.